# Convert an array to Linked List

Tags: java

I just want to convert my array to Singly Linked List , inside the function `convertArrayToLinkedList(int arr[])`. However it is showing an error

```
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to LinkeListImplementation.Node
            head = arr[i];
                      ^
1 error
```

I am unable to fix how can we insert `arr[i]` into `newNode`.

```
import java.util.*;

class LinkeListImplementation{
Node head = null;
class Node{
    Node next = null;
    int data;
    int arr[];
    Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
    Node(int arr[]){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public void convertArrayToLinkedList(int arr[]){
    Node newNode = new Node(arr);
    Node temp = head;
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        newNode.next = head;
        head = arr[i];
    }

    while(temp!=null){
        System.out.print(temp.data+" ");
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}
}

class Main{
public static void main(String[] args){
    LinkeListImplementation LL = new LinkeListImplementation();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int len = sc.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[len];
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    LL.convertArrayToLinkedList(arr);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to convert an array to a linked list you can initialize `Node` class like that

```
class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;
    // Default constructor
    Node(){}
    // when you create a node using the value of arr[i]
    Node(int data){
      this.data = data;
    }
}
```

after initializing the `Node` class `convertArrayToLinkedList(int[] arr)`  method can be-

```
public void convertArrayToLinkedList(int[] arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) return;
  
  Node tHead = new Node();
  Node temp = tHead;
  
  for (int x : arr) {
    temp.next = new Node(x);
    temp = temp.next;
  }
  head = tHead.next;
}
```

after calling `LL.convertArrayToLinkedList(arr);` now you can print the values from main function using the `while` loop like that

```
temp = head;
while (temp != null) {
  System.out.println(temp.data);
  temp = temp.next;
}
```

there are some mistake you made

```
class Node{
    Node next = null;
    int data;
    // there are no need to declare arr[]
    int arr[];
    Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
    // the constructor declaration is not fine
    Node(int arr[]){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I am unable to fix how can we insert `arr[i]` into `newNode`. ..."*

They must be the same data-type.
Variable *arr* is of type *int[]*, and *head* is of type *Node*.

Your *Node* class contains the *arr* array, which isn't entirely necessary.
You'll only need a *Node* for *next*, and an *int* for the value.

Consider the following example.

The static *parse* method here will traverse the provided *arr* array, appending the value to the *next* field of the relevant node.

```java
class Node {
    int value;
    Node next;

    Node() {
    }

    static Node parse(int[] arr) {
        Node head, node = head = new Node();
        for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
            node.setValue(arr[index]);
            if (index + 1 < arr.length) {
                node.setNext(new Node());
                node = node.getNext();
            }
        }
        return head;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Here is an example usage, given the code you provided.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int len = sc.nextInt();
int arr[] = new int[len];
for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
    arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
}

Node node = Node.parse(arr);

while (node != null) {
    System.out.println(node.getValue());
    node = node.getNext();
}
```

Input and output,

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have defined a `Node` that can hold both an `int` and an `int[]`. That is not correct. Each `Node` should only hold a single `int` and a reference to the next node.

```
class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int data;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Now, your converter method should actually return the `Node`(s) you construct; guard against an empty array or null, and actually assign the elements to `Node`(s).

```
public Node convertArrayToLinkedList(int arr[]) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length < 1) {
        return null;
    }
    Node n = new Node(arr[0]), c = n;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        c.next = new Node(arr[i]);
        c = c.next;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Finally, your method to print and display in `main()` might look something like

```
Node n = LL.convertArrayToLinkedList(arr);
while (n != null) {
    System.out.println(n.data);
    n = n.next;
}
```

Comment: But inside the main when I call (Node n = LL.convertArrayToLinkedList(arr);
while (n != null) {
    System.out.println(n.data);
    n = n.next;
} it is showing an error (  error: cannot find symbol
        Node n = LL.convertArrayToLinkedList(arr);
        ^
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class Main
1 error)

Comment: I think you failed to update `convertArrayToLinkedList` as in my answer. Because I ran this code.